# Elasticsearch properties not visible in kibana Terms

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I use elasticsearch `v 7.10.2` with Kibana.

I created an index `ApkHistory` for my object

```
{
  "apkhistory" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "apkId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "appUserCountry" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "include_in_parent" : true,
          "properties" : {
            "countryCode" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "currency" : {
              "properties" : {
                "code" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "name" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "symbole" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "usdunit" : {
                  "type" : "float"
                }
              }
            },
            "indicatif" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "appUserId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "event" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "isFree" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data is saved correctly, but when I want to create a visualization, I only have in Terms or Significant Terms `appUserId.Keyword` and `event.keyword`. I should have them all.

[image]

What is wrong with my mapping?

Thanks

Comment: to be sure: is your index pattern in kibana up to date? do you see all the keyword fields in your index pattern?

Comment: @glenacota yes, i kibana i can see all of the keywords fields. There are all there in my index pattern.

Comment: another couple of questions to be sure: (1) do you have any document with non-empty values for the keyword fields you don't see? (2) have you tried to hit "refresh" for the index pattern from the management page?

Comment: @glenacota (1) I can see all documents, all documents are correctly saved. (2) I click on refresh and one new property appeared over the 10. Maybe i should refresh multiple times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i refresh the index and they appeared. Thanks @glencota.